# Best way to get all Linux system services in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, linux, service

I have NodeJS project working on Linux only (required). It will get system information to put to client via RestAPI. What I've done are get cpu, memory, hard disk/filesystem, network, processes, users, os info, peripherals and removable devices. But I can't get or list all system services like `service --status-all` and should be show like Windows Task Manager - Services Tab
[image]

My API will serialize to JSON object for each service and send to client.
How can I get all services available on Linux system?

Comment: Linux does not really have the concept of a "service". The closest approximation I can think of would be the combination of several different  `systemctl` status printouts (start with `systemctl list-unit-files`) but that's specific to Linux *with systemd*, which may or may not be what you have.

Comment: I have got list of processes but I don't know how to get list of services like apache2, mongod, networking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu supports systemd commands, **list of all services** will be fetched by following command.

```
service --status-all
```

and **list of all services along with details** (service name, service state, active status and description) will be fetched by following command

```
systemctl -l --type service --all
```

or as **root privileges** you can use following command to get all services with details

```
systemctl -r --type service --all
```

Comment: You can get the details of a service by the command :

service status {serviceName}

or

systemctl status {serviceName}